# how to change wallpaper on the lockscreen

Tags: greeter, wallpaper, release-hera

After I update to Hera, I can't change lockscreen wallpaper. Is there any a way to change lockscreen wallpaper and not change the dekstop?

Comment: These instructions helped me - https://www.reddit.com/r/elementaryos/comments/cwisd3/is_there_something_wrong_with_the_new_pantheon/eyc1nft/?utm_medium=android_app&utm_source=share

Answer (score 0):

It is currently not possible to change the Greeter wallpaper of elementary OS.

You can, however, try this branch of Github's Greeter project which would allow to put a wallpaper with an effect blur :

https://github.com/elementary/greeter/tree/blurred-background

But I never test this